# Does soap mixed with water kill plants??

Tags: trees, houseplants, plant-health

I'm doing a science fair project for 8th grade and I'm trying to decide my hypothesis but I'm oblivious .

Comment: This OP is looking for more in-depth about different soaps.  Some soaps have ingredients that are harmful to foliage and/or flowers and it would be nice to be able to know what those ingredients are.  Why are Safer Soaps safer?  Good question, great project for science! Phototoxicity might come into play

Comment: Well, @stormy the other answers do cover other soaps than only dawn. This question is very vague, and not of a high quality.

Comment: If this OP stays with this site, answers/asks questions to further, then we should keep open.

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you mix a lot of soap with a little bit of water.  Soap is a fatty acid and when applied in a thick coat and left on the leaves and stems will burn soft plant tissue.
Your project could easily test this if you can find ten or twelve plants that are all alike (end of season sales anyone?).

Leave three as a control and do nothing, take three and apply soap and water at the recommended rate of 10 ml per liter. For the other two groups apply soap at a much increased concentration.
Spray and observe...

Comment: Different types of soaps and dilutions. Also different exposures, times of spray treatments.